# Ruby On Rails: Sending large pictures using send_data/send_file results in errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.93 and Rails 3.2 and I try to send pictures using the functions `send_data` and `send_file`. Currently I'm using WebBrick as a development server.

In both cases it seems to work fine as long as the picture is smaller then around 330kB. But when the picture becomes larger (say 1MB) Firefox, Maxthon and IE all stop displaying the image and Firefox says that the picture contains errors.

I downloaded the corrupted picture file and compared the filesize with the original picture. On large pictures the file size is around 400 bytes larger.

Here are some code blocks a tried:

```
send_data img.to_blob, :stream => 'false', :filename => 'test.jpg', :type => 'image/jpg', :disposition => 'inline'

send_data( img.to_blob, :filename => "test.jpg" )

send_file( 'C:\WebProjects\RubyTest\public\data\pic3_3.jpg' , :disposition => 'inline')

File.open('C:\WebProjects\RubyTest\public\data\pic3_3.jpg', 'rb') do |f|
   send_data f.read, :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline"
end
```

The funny thing is that with a even larger file Firefox, Maxthon and IE complaint about a corrupted image and the Blackberry Playbook was able to display the picture. On the other hand, the Playbook had problems with some smaller pictures that the other browser displayed correctly.

Btw `.to_blob` is a RMagick function that returns a binary object. But RMagick seems to work correctly.

Comment: Paste your view code as well.

Comment: Just a hunch, but you might want to inspect the actual data in the file, especially the last 400 bytes of the file for a possible error string. I suspect the extra 400 bytes could be an error message.

Comment: @Casper: I compared the original picture file and the one that was downloaded with Maxthon. I found out that the last 68174 bytes of the original picture were at the beginning of the file, even before the HTTP headers. The additional bytes are the HTTP headers that are now in between the chunk of data that was send to early and the normal beginning of the picture. The 68174 bytes that are now at the beginning of the file are missing at the end.

Comment: @Anand: There is no view code. `def get_image      send_file( 'C:\WebProjects\RubyTest\public\data\picture.jpg' , :disposition => 'inline')   GC.start`    end

Comment: Just tried to use send_file on a 3MB pdf and I get the same problem. The end of the file is send before the beginning of the file. Might that be a webbrick problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
[I replaced WEBrick by Thin as you can see on this website.](http://www.psteiner.com/2012/04/how-to-replace-webrick-with-thin-for.html)
It seems that WEBrick has problems with larger files. I don't know if Thin is the final solution, but at least it solved the problem.